# Differences between DartEditor and Dart plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, dart, dart-polymer, dart-editor

I developed a dart/polymer project with the DartEditor. Because the DartEditor has no support for Git I moved to Eclipse and installed the Dart plugin. Now suddenly I get new errors, I didn't get in the Dart Editor and I wonder what the difference could be.
The Dart-SDK and Dartium versions are exactly the same. I copied the corresponding folders from the DartEditor to the Eclipse folder.

The version of the Eclipse plugin is 1.6.0.dev_01_02, of the Dart Editor 1.6.0.dev_01_02, of the Dart-SDK 1.6.0-dev.1.2.

The error messages I get are:

```
Loading polymer transformers...
Serving mastermind web on http://localhost:8080
[Warning from polymer (Linter) on mastermind|web/mm-color-button.html]:
line 2, column 1 of web/mm-color-button.html: Missing definition for <polymer-element>, please add the following HTML import at the top of this file: <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">.
[Warning from polymer (Linter) on mastermind|web/mm-game.html]:
line 2, column 1 of web/mm-game.html: Missing definition for <polymer-element>, please add the following HTML import at the top of this file: <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">.
[Error from polymer (Linter) on mastermind|web/mm-game.html]:
line 3, column 1 of web/mm-game.html: Polymer.dart's implementation of HTML imports are not supported within polymer element definitions, yet. Please move the import out of this <polymer-element>.
Build error:
Transform ImportInliner on mastermind|web/mastermind.html threw error: Could not find asset mastermind|web/mm-game.html.

build failed with errors: {Transform polymer (Linter) on mastermind|web/mm-color-button-line.html threw error: Polymer.dart's implementation of HTML imports are not supported within polymer element definitions, yet. Please move the import out of this <polymer-element>., Transform polymer (Linter) on mastermind|web/mm-line.html threw error: Polymer.dart's implementation of HTML imports are not supported within polymer element definitions, yet. Please move the import out of this <polymer-element>., Transform polymer (Linter) on mastermind|web/mm-line.html threw error: Polymer.dart's implementation of HTML imports are not supported within polymer element definitions, yet. Please move the import out of this <polymer-element>., Transform polymer (Linter) on mastermind|web/mm-game.html threw error: Polymer.dart's implementation of HTML imports are not supported within polymer element definitions, yet. Please move the import out of this <polymer-element>.}
```

Probably it's because of the different Polymer versions. In the DartEditor I have 0.9.5+2 and in Eclipse 0.11.0+5. I thought that pub get would update the packages automatically to the newest version if the dependency is to any.

What did change in polymer? Why are this now errors?

Comment: The error messages seem incomplete. Can you please check them again and format them as code (select the text and press the toolbar-button with the curly braces `[{}]`). To me it seems you have different versions of the polymer package. Please check this too.

Comment: I updated my question with the full error text and the polymer versions.

Answer (score 2):

These are normal messages, I don't think they are caused by the Eclipse plugin.

Can you please check, that you have the `polymer.html` import at the top of each Polymer element definition file

```dart
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<!-- other element imports -->

<polymer-element name='some-name>
  <!-- no elements imports in here or below -->
  <template>
    <!-- style imports are allowed here -->
  </template>
  <script ...>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: No, I don't. This wasn't required before. What should I do about the links between the elements?

Comment: This is a requirement since one of the recent Polymer updates. If you have element imports inside your `<polymer-element>` tag, move them above the `<polymer-element>` tag but below the `polymer.html` import.

Comment: Okay, adding the polymer-element import and moving the element imports outside did clear these errors. But no I get others. My polymer elements do not have a shadow root, so it seems: NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'querySelector'. I will open another question for this.

Answer (score 0):

This was not a difference between the eclipse plugin and the dart editor, but between the different versions of the polymer package. There were many changes in between the two versions and I had to adapt the code accordingly.